# Is there a way to make use both italic and bold in a textview in XCode 4.3.2?

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextview, xcode4.3

I am including some text in a textview and want both regular font and some italicized words. Is this possible to do this or no? If so can someone show me how to do this? I know you can either set the whole text in the textview to either be bold or italic or regular but was wondering if you could mix it up as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from the [`UITextView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html):

> This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color,
>   and text alignment attributes you specify always apply to the entire
>   contents of the text view. To display more complex styling in your
>   application, you need to use a UIWebView object and render your
>   content using HTML.

So it looks like what you want to do is not natively supported.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the information. Could you elaborate in more detail by what you mean "render your content using HTML".

Comment: @Masterminder  What that means is if you want to apply some simple HTML formatting to your text (ie. apply bold or italics to individual sections of text) then you may do so using a `UIWebView`